# On hover on phone number it shows %E2%80%AD before number

Tags: html, wordpress, href, anchor

In my website, when I hover over `547864852` number it shows me `tel:%E2%80%AD547864852%E2%80%AC`. But on click it goes to the correct number. Can anyone suggest me what to do? This happens in my one if WordPress site.

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: "But on click its will goes to correct number" — So do nothing.

Comment: e2 80 ad LEFT-TO-RIGHT OVERRIDE unicode.  try adding ltr to html  (<element dir="ltr">

Comment: Why is that a problem if everything works perfectly? It's just the way your browser treats some special characters

Comment: It is just urlencoding: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding

Answer (score -1):

This is called URL Encoding, difference set of characters in such urls are represented in URL encoding in the back.URL encoding converts characters into a format that can be transmitted over the Internet. For more info see - https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.ASP

If the link does go where you wanted it to, don't worry.